# Interface definition for typescript method parameter problem?

Tags: react-fusioncharts

A method is defined with `ts`. According to the conditions, the order of parameters in the callback method is `a`, `b`, or `b`, `a`.

```
if (props.xxx) {
    props.onChange(a, b)
} else {
    props.onChange(b, a)
}
```

How should this onChange method be described in the interface?

Answer (score 0):

```js
type OnChange = {
    (a: string, b: number): void;
    (a: number, b: string): void;
};

type IProps = {
    xxx: boolean;
    onChange: OnChange;
};
```

Instead of using function overloading, use union types:

```js
interface FooParams {
    xxx: true;
    onChange: (a: string; b: number) => void;
}
interface BarParams {
    xxx: false;
    onChange: (a: number; b: string) => void;
}
type IProps2 = FooParams | BarParams

const App = (props: IProps2) => {
  if (props.xxx) {
    props.onChange('', 1)
  }
}
```